# How can I handle key events in meteor?

Tags: meteor

According to the docs, I should be able to handle key events like `keypress` in the same way I can handle the `click` event, but I feel like I'm missing something.

I've done the following:

```
> meteor create keypressTest
> cd keypressTest
> sed -e 's/click input/keypress body/' -i .bak keypressTest.js
> meteor
```

But when I press keys, nothing shows up in the console like it does when handling the click event.

Are there any examples of working key handling in meteor? I know I can do a workaround in jquery, but would prefer to stick to the clean template events if I can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was missing these two requirements for using key events in the eventmap:

1. The event target must be contained within the template (same as other events)
2. The event target must be an input element that can be typed in

The second point seems consistent with clicking, since a `click *` only fires when clicking on the button, not on the greeting text also contained within the template.

Answer (score 11):

Please note that [keypress is deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress) and you might want to use [textinput](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-textinput) instead.

I do however note that `keydown` and `keyup` are not deprecated, so using one of those might work more reliable than using `keypress`. Note that the documentation specifies the order:

1. `keydown`
2. `keypress`
3. `keyup`

If you want to act upon the press you could use `keydown`; if you want to act upon the lift, use `keyup`. I would prefer the latter given that it still allows you to cancel the keypress by switching to another application before lifting it...

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior (or lack of behavior) with keydown and keyup. I've tested in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome.

Comment: From the document you link to: "The textInput event, originally proposed as a replacement for keypress, was removed in favor of the current beforeinput and input events."

Comment: As @user456584 states, the best option here seems to be the `input` event as that will not only trigger immediately when the key is pressed, but also after the actual data is available in the text field (which might be important).

Answer (score 8):

I can find my 'keypress' events

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    'keypress input': function(e) { console.log('key', e); }
});
```

or in a more usable example

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
      'keyup input': function(event) {
      if (event.which === 13) {
         alert('you hit enter');
         event.stopPropagation();
         return false;
      }
   },
    ...
```

@tom, I didn't get anything on textinput :(

Comment: This worked except `event.charCode` always returns `0`.  I needed to use `event.keyCode`.

Answer (score 1):

Enter will return an `event.charCode = 0`, instead use `event.keyCode` this will return 13.

```
'keypress input': function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('you hit enter');
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
}
```